# Separate carbs and fat in a meal?

Tags: nutrition, boxing

I'm a boxer and I'm trying to cut a little weight while getting enough calories (of the right sort) to be able to train every day (3x high intensity and 3x medium intensity workouts per week). I try to go easy on carbs.

Example: I'm having whole grain pasta with veggie sauce and some tofu for protein for lunch. Is it OK to put some grated cheese on top? I'm not so worried about calories here because I still need more than the average person. I'm asking because I found that the combination takes me much longer to digest (much more than 2 hours). I still feel full after 2.5 hours and have to burp when I run. On the other hand a post workout shake with two tablespoons of oats and one tablespoon of peanut putter in it feels like it's digested in no time. Is that just me or is this normal? What else should I keep in mind?

Comment: So, to be specific, you're asking about combining carbs and fats in a single meal as it directly relates to training?

Comment: Exactly. Especially the last meal before training.

Answer (score -1):

When it come to digestion, quantity and type of nutrients are pivotal. Fatty foods stay  the longest in the stomach that's why the food with cheese is taking longer for you to digest and also it's of a greater quantity compared the workout shake. So proteins follow fats and then lastly carbs take the least time to digest. So if you want to avoid burping consider the small meals of proteins and carbs with less fat.